# Calculate the share of a certain criteria of the total per month

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=22f902299d9aa858e9c3275d2d655252)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(country, sales_date, sales_volume
)
VALUES 
("DE", "2020-01-03", "500"),
("DE", "2020-02-15", "700"),
("DE", "2020-03-27", "180"),
("NL", "2020-01-29", "320"),
("NL", "2020-02-03", "420"),
("NL", "2020-03-20", "420"),
("FR", "2020-01-18", "350"),
("FR", "2020-02-10", "180"),
("FR", "2020-03-30", "970");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
country     YEAR(sales_date)    MONTH(sales_date)   SUM(sales_volume)    sales_share
DE              2020                    1                 500               0.36
DE              2020                    2                 700               0.50
DE              2020                    3                 180               0.14
FR              2020                    1                 350               0.23
FR              2020                    2                 180               0.12
FR              2020                    3                 970               0.65
NL              2020                    1                 320               0.23
NL              2020                    2                 420               0.30
NL              2020                    3                 670               0.47
```

---

In the table above I have different `countries` and their corresponding `sales`. 
Now, I want to calculate the `sales_share` of **each country** **per month** as you can see in the expected results.

```
SELECT 
country,
YEAR(sales_date),
MONTH(sales_date),
SUM(sales_volume)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

How do I have to modify my query so it divides the `sum per country` by the `total of all countries` per month in order to get the `sales_share`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT country, YEAR(sales_date), MONTH(sales_date),
       SUM(sales_volume),
       SUM(sales_volume) / SUM(SUM(sales_volume)) OVER (PARTITION BY country) as ratio
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5bb2246241b7029f8b0fadde4b8f6028